# Finding linearly independent power series solutions of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

So I want to find two linearly independent power series solutions about the point $x_0$ of $(x^2-4)y''+3xy'+y=0$

While solving this, I found the relationship of the variables to be $$c_{k+2}=\frac{k+1}{4(k+2)}c_k$$

After this, I couldn't find the pattern to show the solution as a power series.

I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship you wrote down tells you how to calculate $c_k$ for high values of $k$, given information about $c_k$ for lower values of $k$.

To be more precise, once we specify $c_0$, and $c_1$, your relationship allows you to determine the values of $c_2, c_3, c_4, \dots$

For example, if we take $c_0 = 1, \  c_1 = 0,\ $ then we find that
$$ c_2 = \frac{1}{4\times 2}, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ c_3 = 0, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ c_4 = \frac{1 \times 3}{4^2 \times 2\times 4}, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ c_5 = 0, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \dots $$
Alternatively, if we take $c_0 = 0, \  c_1 = 1, \ $ then we find that
$$ c_2 = 0, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ c_3 = \frac{2}{4\times 3}, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ c_4 = 0, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ c_5 = \frac{2 \times 4}{4^2 \times 3 \times 5}, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \dots$$

Putting these coefficients into our power series $y(x) = \sum_k c_k x^k$, we obtain two linearly independent solutions:
$$ y = 1 +  \frac{1}{4\times 2}x^2 + \frac{1 \times 3}{4^2 \times 2\times 4}x^4 + \dots  $$
$$ y =  x + \frac{2}{4\times 3}x^3 + \frac{2 \times 4}{4^2 \times 3 \times 5}x^5 + \dots  $$

Edit: Reading through your question again, I get the impression that you are expecting a nice formula for the $k$th coefficient. This is rarely the case!

Comment: "This is rarely the case!" Except that here, for example, $$c_{2k}=\frac1{4^{2k}}{2k\choose k}c_0$$

Comment: @Did Well spotted!